# <style> injected in content_scripts doesn't get applied to document element in background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a script set to "run_at": "document_idle", and it injects a  tag into the header. However, attempting to apply the class therein defined to an element later does not cause any change in the element.

manifest.json:

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "make color",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["pageload.js"],
        "run_at": "document_idle"
    }],
    "browser_action": {},
    "permissions": ["*://*/*","activeTab","tabs"]
}
```

pageload.js:

```js
'use strict';

// onload, add our class "highlight"
var css = "\n\t.highlight { background-color: yellow; }\n",
    rstyle = document.createElement('style');

// Append style element to head
document.head.appendChild(rstyle);

//rstyle.type = "text/css";
rstyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
```

background.js (run on button click):

```js
'use strict';

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    // toggle putting the class on the body
    document.body.classList.toggle('highlight');

});
```

When a page loads, I see the  element in the header. When I click the button, I see the "class='highlight'" appear in the stand-alone (background page) dev elements but not the browser dev elements.
Anybody know what I'm missing?
Thank you!

Comment: The background script runs in a separate special hidden background page. You need to use chrome.tabs.executeScript or chrome.tabs.sendMessage to control the web page. See [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567) and [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)

Answer (score 0):

The background script executes in a DOM of its own. To modify the document in the active tab you'll need to use the "activeTab" permission in the manifest's permissions and execute your code in the following way

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, 
function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tabs[0].id,
        {code: "document.body.classList.toggle('highlight');"});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @ScriptKraft, for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Here's ultimately what worked for me--Using messaging between the background and content sources:

```
'use strict';

// onload, add our class "highlight"
var css = "\n\t.highlight { background-color:yellow; }\n",
    rstyle = document.createElement('style');

// Append style element to head
document.head.appendChild(rstyle);

rstyle.type = "text/css";
rstyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "toggle_highlight" ) {
        document.body.classList.toggle('highlight');
    }
  }
);
```

and

```
'use strict';

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // Send a message to the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "toggle_highlight"});
  });
});
```